Laravel UpdateUserRequest validation rule with user id
I have a User model, and this is my update() method in UserController:
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
{
    // Assign authorization
    Gate::authorize('update', $user);
    
    $request->validate([
        'username' => 'required|unique:users,username,' . $user->id,
        // other rules ...
    ]);
    
    // ...
}

I want to keep these validation rules in a separate UpdateUserRequest request:
class UpdateUserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true; // Changed to 'true' to handle authorization logic in UserPolicy
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'username' => 'required|unique:users,username,' . $user->id, // <-- Problem
            // other rules ...
        ];
    }
}

The problem here is that $user is not defined. I have read elsewhere that using a route for this matter is a possible solution, but that's not the proper way of achieving this task.
My question is what is the correct way to pass user information to UpdateUserRequest class?

You have auth()->user()->id or simpler auth()->id()

@matiaslauriti What if the user isn't the one logged in?

@Zakk, Can you share your route defination for this? Are you using implicit model binding in the route-defination ?

@Zakk , I have posted my answer, please check and let me know your feedback. Thanks

@Zakk you never said in your question that you may not have a user logged in...

@matiaslauriti What does that have to do with the topic? How can this information impact the answer? And since when having users logged in or not influenced on other models?

@Zakk how can I know that auth()->id() will not work if you don't tell me that a user can exist? In your original code, you are getting a user every time...


My question is what is the correct way to pass user information to
UpdateUserRequest class?

I assumed you are using laravel 11.X and your route definition is...
Route::put('/users/{user}', [UserController::class, 'update']);

In this scenario you can do it inside the UpdateUserRequest.
class UpdateUserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        // Here you can also interact with your `gates` & `policy`,Check the docs link I provided below to get clear insights.
        return true; 
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        //Scenario 1
        $user = User::find($this->route('user')); //If you are not using `implicit model binding`
        //Scenario 2
        $user = $this->user ; //If you are using `route-model-binding`


        return [
            'username' => 'required|unique:users,username,' . $user->id, // <-- "Issue will be solved"
            // other rules ...
        ];
    }
}

Then in Controller class import & type-hint the FormRequest class i.e. UpdateUserRequest on your Controller method that is missing in your current code.
public function update(UpdateUserRequest $request, User $user)
{
    // Assign authorization
    Gate::authorize('update', $user);

    // Retrieve the validated input data...
     $validated = $request->validated();  // it will by default validate all the input data you set up in the `rule()` of `UpdateUserRequest`
    
    
    // ...
}

For more clear and in-depth insights please check the official-docs here.

I prefer dealing with authorization logic in policy classes. Otherwise, the code will get a bit messy since some parts will be in requests, some in controllers (Gate::authorize()).

This is how I defined my routes: Route::resource('users', UserController::class);

@Zakk, Main logic remain  same and yes you can separate your authorization logic in policy classes, there will be no issue. If you use Route::resource('users', UserController::class); it will by default handle the route model binding.Try the answer and let me know if you stuck any where .And also go through the docs link I provided in the answer where you will get more details.

It did work. Thank you! So the thing is, UpdateModelRequest and StoreModelRequest classes have the model "known" to them.

I have two more questions. A: Is using validated() necessary to trigger validation? Or is it done automatically? B: In order to use validated data, can one just use $request->username or they must use the validated function?

@Zakk , As per official docs when you use Custom form Request like UpdateModelRequest you must call $request->validated(); to retrieve the validated data. And when you are using default Illuminate\Http\Request  object you need to use $request->validate([ ]) and inside the array pass the all the validation field in array key-value pair.
check the link 1) https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic
2) for custom form-request check this :- https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/validation#creating-form-requests

In this case, how to retrieve files (e.g. $request->hasFile('field')) from validated requests, since they are just plain arrays?

"Is using validated() necessary to trigger validation" - when using form requests NO, the validation runs anyway before your controller is handled, this means your validation runs before the Gate::authorize check. This is why it's better to handle the authorization in the form request itself.

"In order to use validated data, can one just use $request->username or they must use the validated function" - you can use $request->$field but there is no guarantee $field has been validated, while using $request->validated()[$field] will throw a missing key error if $field was not a key on the rules list.

What about authorization for other methods, like create and delete? Should they be handled in the controller or elsewhere?

@Zakk , Yes you can handle create & delete same way as that of update.For create there is a tiny difference you can check this link 1) https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/authorization#methods-without-models
For delete you can follow the same logic as of update check the link 2) https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/authorization#policy-methods

You didn't get my question. In the case of store and update, authorization check is better done in request classes. What about authorization for create and delete? Should the Gate::authorize('create', User::class) be present in the create controller method?

@Zakk , "Should they be handled in the controller or elsewhere? " you can also handle it in the route using can() as middlware as well as in Controller.

In my case, I can't use can() as middleware, because I am using Route::resource('users', UserController::class);

@Zakk, In that case you need to use Gate::authorize('create', User::class) inside controller method , there will be np issue. Here create policy method does not require a model-instance. Check here :- https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/authorization#controller-actions-that-dont-require-models
